# not sure why ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end throws exception

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

First of all a background of what i want to achieve,

```
<tr  ng-repeat-start="eachParam in myArray">
    <td rowspan=2>On site</td>
    <td rowspan="2" class = "success">{{eachParam.support}}</td>
    <td class = "warning">FE</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class = "warning">BE</td>
</tr ng-repeat-end>
```

I expected it to create a structure like below:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<table class = "table table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    <!-- Repeat 1-->
    <tr>
      <td rowspan = 2>super parent1</td>
      <td rowspan = 2>parent1.1</td>
      <td>child 1.1.1</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>child 1.1.2</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- Repeat 2-->
    <tr>
      <td rowspan = 2>super parent2</td>
      <td rowspan = 2>parent2.1</td>
      <td>child 2.1.1</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>child 2.1.2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

you can see in the snippet that, i want to repeat those two super parents using `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` so that the intermediate `<tr>` won't be left out while i am out repeating the super parent or the parent.

Please note the `childs` are static element.

Now the exception i am getting is:

> Unterminated attribute, found 'ng-repeat-start' but no matching
>   'ng-repeat-end' found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add ng-repeat-end to the opening of the `tr` tag, not the closing tag. Like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="eachParam in myArray">
    <td rowspan=2>On site</td>
    <td rowspan="2" class = "success">{{eachParam.support}}</td>
    <td class = "warning">FE</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat-end>
    <td class = "warning">BE</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks dude. This exactly was needed.